# Why is my SecAction rule being ignored?

Tags: nginx, waf, debian, mod-security

I'm trying to configure a
[SecAction](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual-%28v2.x%29#secaction) rule to help me tune **ModSecurity 3** following this [How to tune your WAF installation to reduce false positives](https://www.oreilly.com/content/how-to-tune-your-waf-installation-to-reduce-false-positives/) tutorial, but the rule seems to be ignored and the msg is not printed either on `access.log` or `error.log`.

```
SecAction \
    "id:980145,\
    phase:5,\
    pass,\
    t:none,\
    log,\
    noauditlog,\
    msg:\'Incoming Anomaly Score: %{TX.ANOMALY_SCORE}\'"
```

I tried messing with the CRS rules just to see if I could change an existing rule and the changes where effective printing a different message than the original on the `error.log`, but the rule above is ignored. I think the place is so obvious it's not even mentioned on the tutorial, but I'm a newbie.

Checking the [Debug Log](https://www.nginx.com/blog/modsecurity-logging-and-debugging/#Debug-Log) level 9 I could see the following:

```
grep 980145 /var/log/modsec_debug.log

[1630420852] [/image/top.jpg] [4] (Rule: 980145) Executing unconditional rule...
[1630420852] [/image/top.jpg] [4] (Rule: 980145) Executing unconditional rule...
```

But if I grep the error log for the 980145 id, nothing is printed there.

**Server:**

- nginx 1.20.1
- modsecurity 3
- owasp-modsecurity-crs 3.0.0

What is the appropriate `.conf` file and place I should include this rule so that it's not ignored by ModSecurity when processing the rules?

Comment: You should put this `SecAction` into the REQUEST-900-EXCLUSION-RULES-BEFORE-CRS.conf (rename/copy the original file). This file loaded before any other rules (except those which are in default modsecurity.conf file).

Comment: @airween, I tried placing the rule on that file, but it still didn't print the message on the error log.

Comment: I just changed the directive `error_log` on the `nginx.conf` file and it printed the message. I see the options are `debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit, alert, or emerg`. It was configured with `notice` and I replaced it with `debug`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the directive `error_log` on the `nginx.conf` file.

The options are `debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit, alert, or emerg`. It is configured for `notice` by defaul and that message from the rule 980145 is considered info for Nginx. I replaced it with the `info` option and it printed the message as follow on the `error.log` file:

```
2021/09/14 17:36:40 [info] 23969#23969: *104083 ModSecurity: Warning ...... [msg "Incoming Anomaly Score: 0"]
2021/09/14 17:36:40 [info] 23969#23969: *104083 ModSecurity: Warning ...... [msg "Incoming Anomaly Score: 0"]
2021/09/14 17:36:40 [info] 23969#23969: *104083 ModSecurity: Warning ...... [msg "Incoming Anomaly Score: 0"]
```